# How can I make swagger-ui (docker) use a specific request URL?

Tags: docker, swagger

I am looking at swagger-ui as a way to demonstrate the use of a REST API. I'm using the docker image for that, starting it like this:

```
docker run -p 8090:8080 -e SWAGGER_JSON=/pgx/swagger.json -v $PWD:/pgx  swaggerapi/swagger-ui
```

Then I try one REST call. But the request is sent to the URL of the swagger server:

```
curl -X GET "http://localhost:8090/token" -H  "accept: application/json"
```

whereas the server I want to use is on `http://localhost:7007`

Is that possible ? I could not find a parameter/setting to make that happen ...

Comment: Does your `swagger.json` file contain `host`/`basePath` (if it's OAS2) or `servers` (if it's OAS3)?

Comment: No it does not. I just added  `host` and that gives me what i wanted. Can I pass that as a variable to the docker run command ?

Comment: I don't quite understand this; are you running another instance of app hosting Swagger on `localhost:7007` ?

Comment: I'm running swagger UI locally on my laptop, but the REST service proper runs elsewhere (I also have a copy running on my laptop on port 7007 for testing). I was looking at swagger-ui as an easy way for developers to learn about the REST API and exercise them against the actual REST service. That service does not run Swagger-UI and will not run it.

Answer (score 1):

It can be defined in the json/yaml file like shown in
https://swagger.io/docs/specification/api-host-and-base-path/

If someone is using annotations here's an example for php zircote lib:

```
 * @OA\Server(
 *      url="https://api.example.com",
 * ),
 * @OA\Server(
 *      url="http://localhost",
 * ),
```

Obs: note that the "Server" is in singular, and that you can create multiple Server definitions.